# Непонятки с размером билда после смены веток

Tags: android, unity3d, git, apk

У меня в проекте есть основная рабочая ветка(основная). С неё я ответвился на другую(побочная). На ней добавлял новые файлы.
Потом на время  перешел на основную ветку. Делал на ней изменения.
Затем снова перешел на побочную. Смерджил на неё изменения с основной и продолжил дальше работать на побочной ветке. Когда я собрал билд на побочной(игра в Unity)  апк весило абстрактных 106 мб.
Меня не устроила эта ветка и я перешел на основную и собрал билд на ней. На ветке нету файлов и прочего которые были на побочной. Но билд весит так же.
Можете растолковать почему так ? И как можно изменить вес на основной ветке. Заранее всем спасибо

Comment: А дельта по файлам между основной и побочной веткой по размеру какая?

Comment: не подскажете как это посмотреть\проверить?

Comment: к программе git, и всем этим веткам-шметкам вопрос явно не имеет никакого отношения. *вам надо выполнить очистку сборочного каталога от результатов предыдущей сборки, а потом собрать заново*. при использовании программы *make* обычно для этого разработчики создают цель `clean`, `dist-clean` и т.д. и т.п. как и чем вы собираете — не имею понятия, но что-то аналогичное по смыслу наверняка должно присутствовать.

Comment: Вы были правы. Это я затупил и проблема совсем не в гите. Спасибо